# Drop duplicate fields with same name after join operation in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, bigdata, aws-glue

When I perform a join on two DynamicFrame, comparing fields with the same name, the resultant DynamicFrame retains both the fields, but a '.' is added to the field name of the right dynamic frame.

```
datasource0 => id, name
datasource1 => id, address
datasource2 = Join.apply(frame1 = datasource0, frame2 = datasource1, keys1 = "id", keys2 = "id")
datasource2 => id, name, .id, address
```

To remove the duplicate field I use`drop_fields`, but it does not work when '.' is a prefix

```
datasource2.drop_fields(['.id'])
datasource2 => id, name, .id, address
```

How to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, I enclosed the offending field name with '`' (backtick).

```
datasource2.drop_fields(['`.id`'])
datasource2 => id, name, address
```